# when i start for loop, the loop getting 0,0,1,2,3.. instead of 0,1,2,3

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, for-loop

```
if __name__ == '__main__':

    l=[]
    s=[]
    for _ in range(int(input())):
        name = input()
        score = float(input())
        l.append(name)
        s.append(score)
    mx=max(s[0],s[1])
    smin=min(s[0],s[1])
    n=len(s)
    for i in range(2,n):
        if(mx>s[i]):
            smin=mx
            mx=s[i]
        elif(s[i]<smin) and \
        max!=s[i]:
         smin=s[i]
    ind=smin
    sminval=s.index(ind)
    g=0
    for i in range(n):
        index_sec=s.index(s[i])
        print(index_sec)
        if(smin==s[i])and\
         sminval!=index_sec:
            x=s[i]   
        g=g+1
    y=l[sminval]
```

**INPUT**

```
5
Harry
37.21
Berry
37.210
Tina
37.2
Akriti
41
Harsh
39
```

**OutPut**

```
0
0
2
3
4
```

while I get this type of index value(i). I can't able to locate correct index of element,
I need explanation of why this is happening?

Comment: What are `mx` and `smin` supposed to contain? I don't understand the logic  in the `if` statements that set them.

Comment: `index()` returns the index of the first matching value. If you have duplicates in the list, you'll get the lowest index of them.

Comment: Your list has `37.21` in index 0 and 1, so it prints `0` twice.

Answer (score 2):

This isn't very structured code, so it is hard to figure out what you really want it to do. I can't fix it for you. If you want to know what is happening, however, here is a walkthrough.

The line "`index_sec=s.index(s[i])`" is going to return the *first* index in list "s" that matches the value found at location i. This will be a unique index only if all the scores in `s` are unique.

However, Harry and Berry both have scores of "37.2". So when you look up the index of Harry's score, and you a lookup the value of Berry's score, you will not get Harry and Berry... you will get whichever one is first in the list... Harry in this case... both times.

To state it differently, when you take Harry's score and look it up, you get Harry. But when you take Berry's score and look it up, you also get Harry since Harry is the first item in the list that has that score. Since Harry is in index 0, that results in "0" followed by "0".

Comment: the thing is i need to find the second minimum value, and also need to find, is anybody having same second score, so that i used for loop to check is anybody having the same value as like as harry. In that I'm getting error that i mentioned above

Comment: You technically aren't getting an error. What you are getting is a behavior that you didn't expect. However, you didn't really explain the overall purpose of the code and why the output is wrong... so it is impossible to comment on the correct way to fix the code.

Comment: Maybe not the most elegant way, but if you are still working on this, one way to go is to not use the "index" method of the list to find what you want. Instead, code your own function. Your custom function could return all matches and not the first match, and then you can change your code to expect a list of answers and not a single value.

Answer (score 0):

Being completely honest, I have also no idea what is going one, what is the goal.
All I can say is, you used the max() and min() method wrong.
What you are looking for is the biggest and smallest value in between the first item of list s and the second item of s.
What you meant is :

```
mx=max(s[0],s[len(s)-1])
smin=min(s[0],s[len(s)-1])
```

However, also this wouldn't be correct, as this would check only between the first and the last item. But you want the biggest out of all items.
So the correct syntax is:

```
mx=max(s)
smin=min(s)
```

Besides that, I can't really help as I have no clue what is the scope of the code.

Comment: the thing is i need to find the second minimum value so i used mx to find the maximum value of first two number similarly smin for min value of first two number. then i used for loop to find the second min value. then after i used again for to find is there any number as same as second minimun value. in that i'm getting error that i mentioned above. sorry i am completely new to python ,